# OneToOne mapping by code nhibernate 3.2

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to upgrade a project and use the build in code mapper.

I have 2 entities:

```
public class Person {
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User {
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual User Person { get; set; }
}
```

The database structure is like this:

```
table: users, fields: id
table: people, fields: id, userId
```

With FluentNHibernate i could map it like this:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
 public UserMap() {
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  HasOne(x => x.Person).PropertyRef("User").Not.LazyLoad();
 }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person> {
 public PersonMap() {
  Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
  References(x => x.User).Column("UserId").Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
 }
}
```

But is can't get it working with NH 3.2 build in code mapper.
This is what i have done so far.

```
OneToOne(x=>x.Person, m => {
 m.PropertyReference(typeof(Person).GetProperty("User"));
});

OneToOne(x=>x.User, m => {});
```

Now the relation is mapped on User.Id and Person.Id but personid and userid can be different.
It's also possible that a user has no person.

```
from Users user0_ left outer join People person1_ on user0_.Id=person1_.Id
```

I think i have to specify that Person -> User is mapped with the UserId column but how?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you were using `References()` in Fluent, you need to convert that to `ManyToOne()`:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMapping<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        OneToOne(x => x.Person,
                 x => x.PropertyReference(typeof(Person).GetProperty("User")));
    }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        ManyToOne(x => x.User,
                  x => x => { x.Column("UserId"); x.NotNullable(true); });
    }
}
```

Two notes:

- The type of `User.Person` should be `Person`, not user (that's probably just a bad edit)
- `.Not.LazyLoad()` is almost always a bad idea. See [NHibernate is lazy, just live with it](http://ayende.com/blog/4573/nhibernate-is-lazy-just-live-with-it)

Comment: thanx! I was only thinking in onetoone relations, not manytoone, works great. And the lazy load was needed for medium trust, i will try not to use it in nh 3.2 (maybe noproxy)